# Conditional Global Lambdas in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I have some python scripts that have behavior depending on conditionals passed by the user when the script is run.

Let's say I have two lambdas; `verbose_print` and `math_foo`, which I want to use to to conditionally do certain things in my python script depending on whether my `-m` or `-v` flags are set.

```
from __future__ import print_function #  Future-proofing
import argparse    #args

verbose_print = lambda x: 0 
math_foo = lambda x, y: 0 

def main_func(args):
  verbose_print("WILL ONLY PRINT WHEN VERBOSE" )
  #other main function stuff
  conditional_result = math_foo(12,45)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    started_at = time.time()
    #declare argparse logic separately from main functionality  
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-m', '--use_math',   action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args() 
    verbose_print("Began...") # won't print since this will always be lambda x:0
    global verbose_print
    verbose_print = lambda x: print(x) if args.verbose and not args.quiet else 0
    global math_foo
    math_foo = lambda x, y: x^(x+y) if args.use_math else y
    main_func(args) #run main function       
    finished_at = time.time()        
    verbose_print("Finished (Took {} seconds)".format((finished_at-started_at)))
```

This approach demonstrably works, but I'm curious about whether there's a more pythonic solution to this kind of thing. For example, if I ever wanted to use this file as an `import` but still wanted log verbose events, I would need to redefine my lambda in that new file. Instead of two lambdas, what if there were eleven? I don't want to set eleven lambdas by hand every time I import!

Is there a better way of handing this kind of conditional behavior? I'm planning on using python for a lot more personal scripting and I'd like to know whether I'm going down the right road.

Comment: sounds like a job for the `logging` module. You can simply set logger's log-level, or even maintain two different loggers, each with its own level.

Comment: An excellent solution to my example, but what if the lambda was something less print-y, like `math_foo = lambda x, y: x^(x+y) if args.use_math else y`?

Comment: Slightly more efficient, since you aren't wrapping `print`: `verbose_print = print if args.verbose and not args.quiet else lambda x: 0`. (Assuming you aren't updating `args` during the course of the run...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I see something like `verbose_print = lambda x: 0` I curse the horrible tutorials that try to explain `lambda` in this strange way. lambdas are anonymous functions that are used when you don't want define a named function.... but that's exactly what the assignment does. Just define the print function and set `verbose` in your main when you process args.

```
verbose = False

def verbose_print(msg):
    global verbose
    if verbose:
        print(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    started_at = time.time()
    #declare argparse logic separately from main functionality  
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-m', '--use_math',   action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args() 
    verbose_print("Began...") # won't print since this will always be lambda x:0
    global verbose
    verbose = args.verbose and not args.quiet
    global math_foo
    math_foo = lambda x, y: x^(x+y) if args.use_math else y
    main_func(args) #run main function       
    finished_at = time.time()        
    verbose_print("Finished (Took {} seconds)".format((finished_at-started_at)))
```

Comment: this is true stories :) +1

Comment: This was the solution I went with, the only variation I made was to get rid of `global verbose ` and  `global math_foo ` in my `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement since they were throwing syntax errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in the comments you should use the logging module

```
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action="count", help="verbose level... repeat up to -vvvv.")

...
args.verbose = min(args.verbose,4)
my_logging_logger.setLevel("CRITICAL ERROR WARN INFO DEBUG".split()[args.verbose])
```

likewise if it was something else

```
some_fn = lambda x:0
data = {"verbose":lambda x:x**2+sqrt(x),"quiet":lambda x:-1}
for k in dir(args): #I think you can do this ... I dont use argparse enough
   if k in data:
       some_fn = getattr(args,k)
       break;
```

Comment: Interesting solution! I think it might be `vars(args)` instead of `dir(args)` but I'll give this a shot.